# Robotium with support.v4 ViewCompat throws NoSuchMethodError on load

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, robotium

I'm using Robotium to automate my app testing. My app has 1 activity (ActionBarActivity) and 2 fragments (using support.v4.app.Fragment). The app works fine but when I attempt to run a Robotium test, I get an error when attempting to create a new Solo instance.

```
solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
```

Logcat output:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/com.mycompany.mytrip.test-1/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:304)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:225)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at com.mycompany.mytrip.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
W/ActivityManager( 1229): Error in app com.mycompany.mytrip running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.mytrip.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}:
W/ActivityManager( 1229):   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
W/ActivityManager( 1229):   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/com.mycompany.mytrip.test-1/base.apk)
D/AndroidRuntime( 5209): Shutting down VM
```

Any suggestion much appreciated!

Comment: Just a thought: The error messages shows classes from the v7 support libraries. You write that you use support.v4.app.Fragment. Is it possible that your test project includes both the v4 and v7 support libraries?

Comment: It does include both - v7 for ActionBarActivity and v4 for Fragments:

From my MainActivity:


`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`

Comment: I've checked my `gradle.build` and I'm only importing v7 library. As I understand v4 libraries are included in v7...

Comment: That could be the issue. android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity is included in the v7 appcompat library and the documentation for this library says: ... This library depends on the v4 Support Library. If you are using Ant or Eclipse, make sure you include the v4 Support Library as part of this library's classpath. ...

Comment: I'm using Android Studio and Gradle and v7 is added as dependency: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'`. I don't think I need v4 as dependency in this case. Either way, adding it didn't fix the issue

Comment: Then I am out of ideas, sorry.